# Are communication service questions appropriate?

Tags: discussion, communication

I'm not sure whether questions about communication service utilities are appropriate or off-topic...

Questions like:

- Home network wiring
- Cable TV installation issues
- Internet service installation issues
- Satellite TV installation issues

What are your thoughts?

-M

Answer (score 4):

Home network wiring definitely yes.  The others would depend on the type of question: they all have aspects that overlap with home network wiring, like "How can I extend my cable TV to every room in the house?", or the recent "[Cable Modem won't work upstairs, only downstairs](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/2118/22)".  But questions like "Comcast or Qwest?" should be off-topic (two cable TV providers in the US, for people elsewhere).

Comment: I see the question I linked to has just been closed.  I guess people don't agree with me that it's on topic. :)

Comment: I think the problem with that question is that it was too much about the modem (Splitter), not so much about running the cables.